# Variable not taking value in a loop [Batch]

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to execute the following batch but not able to comprehend the behaviour of `varvpccidr`

```
set filetemp=temp.txt
    for /F "delims=" %%a in (%filetemp%) do (
            set  varvpccidr=%%a
            echo [%%a] {%varvpccidr%] 
    )
```

**Output:**

> [172.25.243.0/25 ] []

**temp.txt contains:**

> 172.25.243.0/25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set filetemp=temp.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (%filetemp%) do (
        set  varvpccidr=%%a
        echo [%%a] [!varvpccidr!] 
)   

endlocal
```

The reason why it's not working as is has to do with the fact that, at the time the `for` command is evaluated (and it's the *entire* four lines from `for` to the closing parenthesis), `varvpccidr` does not yet have a value.

By using *delayed* expansion, you defer the expansion of the variable until the latest possible point, the `echo` line itself.